# Grouping similar field data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have a table that accepts common data from multiple input channels and consists of ~100,000 rows.

One of the fields, stores the name of an employees functional manager. In the organisation, there are ~100 of these functional managers.

The issue I have is, as there are multiple input channels, different reporting systems have used a different name format for these managers.

For example, John Smith could be stored as;

```
John Smith
Smith, John
Smith John
```

This is a bit of nightmare now as we are looking to use this functional manager field as mechanism for reporting, which would mean we would need to sort or group by individual functional managers.

The data becomes legacy after each quarter, so we are happy to clean and format the functional manager field.

The question is, is there a simple way to do group these managers, even though their names are in different formats, I am looking for a way that does not involve me going one by one through each functional manager with a statement like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET fm_name = "John Smith" where fm_name like "%John%" and fm_name like "Smith";
```

For example; programmatically, I could take the first record, break the name into its first and last name strings, then match similar records and update them. Then move to the next record. Is something like that possible in MySQL or would I be better to do that in the layer above.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. You ask "is there a simple way to do this" but it doesn't seem to refer to any specific question. If you need to sort/group by them, I don't think you can pull anything performant if your data isn't more consistent.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't even match the question itself!

Comment: @Jeto I have updated the question.

Comment: @cdaiga I think the title matches perfectly, I am looking to group the data as is but I don't think it would be possible, so I would happily accept a solution that offers an easier way to clean the data. Than doing it manually for each manager.

Comment: Ok I now get the question clearer @Glen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can come up with a normalizing function `name_normalize(string)` that yields `George H. W. Bush` given either that exact input or `Bush, George H. W.`, then you can do

```
  GROUP BY name_normalize(name)
```

and get what you want without mucking around with the data in your table.

This is such a function. It hacks around with MySQL's string functions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

```
IF(LOCATE(',',@name1) = 0,                               --need to change?
   @name1,                                               -- no, return original
   LEFT(CONCAT_WS(' ',                                   -- yes, concatenate...
                  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name1, ',',-1)), --  after last ,
                  @name1),                               --  whole name
        LENGTH(                                         -- cut to original name length
                REPLACE(@name1,',',''))))               -- but without the comma
```

Substitute the name of your column for `@name`. And beware, this is sensitive to the number of spaces after the comma.

You'd be wise to define this function as a stored function. For one thing, you can handle the odd cases better. For another, it's kind of long to write in a query.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Your answer combined with [this](https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) has got me 90% of the way. Just the outliers now. :)

Comment: Yeah. The outliers. Aren't they the struggle?

Comment: Thankfully there doesn't appear to be to many. I have formats John Smith, Smith John and Smith, John done. There is for some reason a few Smith,John with no space floating about. I have put the problem back over to the teams were the data enters from. They should really all be using the same format. Thanks again.